# Keeping track of processed jms messages

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ, Spring.

Is there any way by which I can keep track of all processed messages. I have to keep track what all messages has been processed. I also want to review these processed messages at later stage.

- Should i use database for this?
- Is there any good library that can make this operation easy
- I do not want to make table in database for every kind of model object

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail for someone to provide an answer. It sounds like some type of auditing is what your looking for. 'Keep Track' is pretty vague. You could just put a message to a log. you could also avoid numerous database tables by serializing the payload or the whole message to a database field at each stage of processing.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would suggest that you either log and/or record the messages into the database.  If you simply want to review the messages later, simple logging may suffice.  If you need to do transactional rollup/searching through a UI, then the database is better.

However, you can also achieve what you want with ActiveMQ virtual destinations.  With this, you can have 1 destination forward to 2 other destinations.  Then your app could listen on 1 destination, and a copy of the message would sit on the other for your review.  For example:

```
  <broker persistent="false" useJmx="false" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">
    <destinationInterceptors>
      <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        <virtualDestinations>
          <compositeQueue name="MY.QUEUE">
            <forwardTo>
              <queue physicalName="MY.QUEUE.PROCESS" />
              <topic physicalName="MY.QUEUE.REVIEW" />
            </forwardTo>
          </compositeQueue>
        </virtualDestinations>
      </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    </destinationInterceptors>

  </broker>
```

Would define a queue MY.QUEUE where each message would end up in BOTH the .PROCESS and .REVIEW queues.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would use a database.
2. Perhaps you could use an ORM such as Hibernate, but JDBC or SpringTemplates may be better.
3. Rather than making a separate table for each model object, make a 'message' table and serialize the uncommon portions into a payload blob (or text).  You could then use a utility to deserialize the message for review (or playback) later.

Answer (score 0):

Kartik,

This is a good programming question, but it's more of a what should I program question rather than a "How can I do this" question.  It's hard to answer a "What should I program question" because what you should program depends directly on what you need.  At best, we can only guess at what you really need.

If you need to update the processed JMS messages, then a database will make it easy to update.  If you need to prove that nobody updated a "logged" entry, then a database might not do the job.

Let's say this log is used to see which very slow to process messages still need to complete.  Then a database will provide easy searching, provided that the person searching knows SQL.   However, if the log is more of an archive, then the database just adds overhead to the entire process, a structured file will do.

In Java there is JDBC for writing and retrieving to databases, and it is not a hard API to use.  Then again, there is also a number of decent logging frameworks, and of course there is always FileOutputStream.  Without knowing how this log is to be used, it is very difficult to determine which techniques are really overkill, likewise it's not possible to know which techniques are not quite enough.

Go back and review how the log is to be used, and then evaluate if the features that databases provide are overkill.

Cheers,
Ed